# Yii console application: is it possible to group into folder the commands?

Tags: php, yii, console

I've a 'big' console application, with a lot of commands

We're cleaning the design, but actually we'd like to group some commands into folders... but is there a way to call a command from a subfolder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [CConsoleApplication.commandMap](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CConsoleApplication/#commandMap-detail), that allows you to specify all commands you want but you have to specify the full path. I beleave you can do this as part of your build process.